# Combinatorics - Counting the number of binary strings with specified length and sum, with substring constraints

Tags: combinatorics, binary

Suppose I have a string of bits of length R. The sum of the bits must be equal to S, so there are S ones and R-S zeros. The longest string of ones cannot exceed X in length. Also the number of places spanning the first and the last 1 (inclusive) cannot exceed Y in length.

How many permutations exist that satisfy these constraints? I am looking for a general formula as a function of R, S, X, Y.

For example, the case where R = 12, S = 6, X = 2, Y = 9 has 37 solutions, which are listed below.

```
 0     0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1
 0     0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1
 0     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1
 0     0     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1
 0     0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1
 0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     1
 0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1
 0     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0
 0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     0
 0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
 1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
 1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
 1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     1     1     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     1     1     0     1     1     0     0     0     0
```

My current line of thought is to consider the sum of each string of ones as parts of a composition of S and develop a formula as some variation on 'stars and bars'...

Assume $X \leq S \leq Y \leq R$ so that the problem is well-defined.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First, let us ignore the $y$ condition, so the constraints are that the string is length $r$, there are $s$ ones, and there are no more than $x$ ones in a row.

Consider the "gaps" between the zeroes. There are $r-s+1$ such gaps; $r-s-1$ are in between two adjacent zeroes, and there are two more at the right and left ends. Let $a_i$ be the number of ones in the $i^{th}$ gap. Then $a_0+a_1+\dots+a_{r-s}=s$, and each $0\le a_i\le x$. The number of solutions to this equation can be counted using inclusion exclusion as
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{r}{x+1}\right\rfloor}\binom{r-s+1}{i}(-1)^i\binom{r-i(x+1)}{r-s}
$$
Now, let the above formula be $f(r,s,x)$. If we add the $y$ condition back in, then the answer to your question is
$$
f(y,s,x)+(r-y)\times \sum_{i=1}^xf(y-i-1,s-i,x)
$$
The $f(y,s,x)$ term accounts for sequences whose ones all occur in the first $y$ places. For everything else, there are $r-y$ choices for where the last one occurs. The index $i$ represents the length of the block of ones containing that last one, which is preceded by a $0$.

You can test this formula [here](https://repl.it/@mearnest/FoolhardyRevolvingAutocad).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following question:

$\dagger$ What is the number of 0-1 sequences of length $Y$ with exactly $S$ many '1's but no subsequence of $X+1$ consecutive '1's?

I will only address the case that $X+1$ divides $Y$ and leave the general case to you.

Let us split the sequence of length $Y$ into chunks of length $X+1$ and then put exactly one '0' into each of these chunks. This can be done in $(X+1)^{Y/(X+1)}$ many ways and guarantees that there is no subsequence of $X+1$ many consecutive '1's. We may now insert the '1's. There are ${Y - Y/(X+1) \choose S}$ many possible combinations and thus
$$(X+1)^{Y/(X+1)} \cdot {Y - Y/(X+1) \choose S}$$
is the answer to $\dagger$.

Now, there are $R-Y+1$ many ways in which we can insert this subsequence into our entire sequence (we may add $0,1, \ldots,$ or all $R-Y$ remaining '0' at the beginning of the sequence). This yields the final answer:
$$
\left(R-Y+1 \right) \cdot (X+1)^{Y/(X+1)} \cdot {Y - Y/(X+1) \choose S}
$$

Comment: If $X=3, S=3, Y=6, R=7$, shouldn't the answer be $\binom{7}{3}-5=30$?

Comment: @user84413 I didn't check your calculation, but I definitely need to have chunks of length $X+1$.

Comment: If $X=2, S=3, Y=6, R=7$, I think the answer should be $\binom{7}{3}-5-5=25$.  (In any case, the answer should be less than $\binom{7}{3}=35$.)